# Div with "close" functions on more than one page

Tags: jquery, function

I have a div called "alert-box-close" that will appear on the page and be closed on X and reappear after 1 minut (just for testing purposes, after that the expiring time will be 30 days).

The problem is that I have three pages that need the same div, but if it's closed on one of the pages, it should appear if another page is opened. With this code in each of pages will reappear only when the indicated time is expired.
How to correct this?
Thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// Add hours function
  Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
      this.setTime(this.getTime() + 60000); // 60 seconds for testing
      return this;
  }
  //Hide div click
  $('.alert-box-close').click(function() {
      //Get time after 24 hours
      var after24 = new Date().addHours(10).getTime();
      //Hide div
      $('#alert-box-news').hide(300);
      //Set desired time till you want to hide that div
      localStorage.setItem('desiredTime', after24);
  });
  //If desired time >= currentTime, based on that HIDE / SHOW
  function checkStorage() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      if (localStorage.getItem('desiredTime') >= currentTime) {
          $('#alert-box-news').hide();
      } else {
          $('#alert-box-news').show();
      }
  }
  //Check logic on load
  checkStorage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert-box-news" class="alert-box alertboxone alerthidden">
  <img src="https://no-cache.hubspot.com/cta/default/4409803/2e194850-79d4-4b68-bd48-dc8e559edd96.png"/>
  <img class="alert-box-close closeone" id="close-alert-box-news" src="https://www.atakinteractive.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/closeiframe.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Include your HTML too

Comment: Html added above